# How to print all rows based on two conditions related two different columns?

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following set of data,

```
ATOM     19  O   WAT     2      -5.435   5.542  -3.646  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     20  H1  WAT     2      -4.824   5.163  -2.982  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     21  H2  WAT     2      -5.318   6.499  -3.469  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     22  O   WAT     3       5.959   0.828   3.228  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     23  H1  WAT     3       5.425   1.196   2.482  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H2  WAT     3       6.711   1.472   3.201  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     25  O   WAT     4      -1.704  -4.348  -2.017  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     26  H1  WAT     4      -1.895  -3.911  -1.145  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     27  H2  WAT     4      -1.980  -5.267  -1.782  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     28  O   WAT     5      -3.222  -3.303   5.524  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     29  H1  WAT     5      -2.934  -3.466   4.594  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H2  WAT     5      -3.063  -2.335   5.580  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     31  O   WAT     6       5.528  -4.121  -0.508  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     32  H1  WAT     6       6.456  -3.823  -0.552  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     33  H2  WAT     6       5.492  -4.428   0.428  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     34  O   WAT     7       4.329   2.267   1.528  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     35  H1  WAT     7       4.574   2.208   0.572  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     36  H2  WAT     7       4.370   3.237   1.645  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     37  O   WAT     8      -6.042  -5.320  -1.141  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     38  H1  WAT     8      -6.693  -4.716  -0.701  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     39  H2  WAT     8      -5.277  -5.191  -0.531  1.00  0.00           H
```

I want to check if the string of column 3=O and the value of column 8 >0.0, in this case I need to print this line and the following three lines.

I can print lines fits one conditions but I cannot join all conditions together

```
cat <inputfile>| awk '$8>0'
```

the output will be

```
ATOM     22  O   WAT     3       5.959   0.828   3.228  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     23  H1  WAT     3       5.425   1.196   2.482  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H2  WAT     3       6.711   1.472   3.201  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     28  O   WAT     5      -3.222  -3.303   5.524  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     29  H1  WAT     5      -2.934  -3.466   4.594  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H2  WAT     5      -3.063  -2.335   5.580  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     34  O   WAT     7       4.329   2.267   1.528  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     35  H1  WAT     7       4.574   2.208   0.572  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     36  H2  WAT     7       4.370   3.237   1.645  1.00  0.00           H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant "print this line" and not "delete". You can set a counter if column3 contains `O` and column8 is greater than 0. Print the line if the counter is greater zero
and decrement the counter.

```
$ awk '$3=="O" && $8>0{ p=4 } p-->0' file
ATOM     22  O   WAT     3       5.959   0.828   3.228  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     23  H1  WAT     3       5.425   1.196   2.482  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H2  WAT     3       6.711   1.472   3.201  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     28  O   WAT     5      -3.222  -3.303   5.524  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     29  H1  WAT     5      -2.934  -3.466   4.594  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H2  WAT     5      -3.063  -2.335   5.580  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     34  O   WAT     7       4.329   2.267   1.528  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     35  H1  WAT     7       4.574   2.208   0.572  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     36  H2  WAT     7       4.370   3.237   1.645  1.00  0.00           H
TER
```

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: FWIW I'd write `p-->0` as `p&&p--` to protect against `p` wrapping around if the input file is massive. Given that construct you don't need to test for `>0` since the compound condition will become false when `p` equals `0` and so can never become negative. I'd also name it `c` for `count` rather than `p` for `print` to avoid the control coupling you get when naming  a variable based on what you'll do based on it's value rather than just based on what it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3 == "O" && $8 > 0.0{x=NR+3}(NR<=x){print }' file
```

output

```
ATOM     22  O   WAT     3       5.959   0.828   3.228  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     23  H1  WAT     3       5.425   1.196   2.482  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H2  WAT     3       6.711   1.472   3.201  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     28  O   WAT     5      -3.222  -3.303   5.524  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     29  H1  WAT     5      -2.934  -3.466   4.594  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H2  WAT     5      -3.063  -2.335   5.580  1.00  0.00           H
TER
ATOM     34  O   WAT     7       4.329   2.267   1.528  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     35  H1  WAT     7       4.574   2.208   0.572  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     36  H2  WAT     7       4.370   3.237   1.645  1.00  0.00           H
TE
```

R